# left join alle topics only last post order by sticky and last post DESC

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

i am trying to get all topics based on a forum ID.
Those topics need to be ordered by sticky first and then by last post date secondly.

I have this query, working almost fine but it doesn't order the topics in the way i want.

```
SELECT 
    forum_posts.posted_by, 
    forum_posts.posted, 
    forum_topics.id, 
    forum_topics.subject, 
    forum_topics.sticky, 
    forum_topics.closed 
FROM 
    forum_posts 
LEFT JOIN 
    forum_topics 
ON 
    forum_topics.id=forum_posts.topic_id 
WHERE forum_topics.forum_id=$forumdata->id 
GROUP BY forum_topics.id 
ORDER BY forum_posts.posted DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY forum_topics.sticky ASC, forum_posts.posted DESC`???

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminat

Comment: There's no LEFT JOIN here, as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS will demonstrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, then you only need to make a slight change to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
    forum_topics.sticky,          -- just add this
    forum_posts.posted DESC;
```

However, as you are selecting non aggregate columns, my hunch is that you should really be using a subquery to figure out the latest post:

```
SELECT
    ft.*, fp1.*
FROM forum_posts fp1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT topic_id, MAX(posted) AS max_posted
    FROM forum_posts
    GROUP BY topic_id
) fp2
    ON fp1.topic_id = fp2.topic_id AND
       fp1.posted = fp2.max_posted
LEFT JOIN forum_topics ft
    ON fp1.id = ft.topic_id
ORDER BY
    ft.sticky;
```

Comment: yes, but... the list is ordered now by sticky DESC. but the topics are not ordered by last post date descending..

Comment: @DirkTeur Your query has bigger problems than `ORDER BY`.  Forget about the ordering and tell us more about your data model.  What do each of these tables represent?

Comment: one table represents the topics, with topic name, sticky and other informatie which is not important for now. the other one is the posts table with all the comments. all posts have a topic_id column and a posted column with a timestamp. i would like to get the list of all topics, ordered on sticky first and then ordered on last post timestamp. :$

Comment: @DirkTeur I gave what I believe is a query on track with what you actually want here.  Try it out, and leave feedback.  If this isn't what you want, then I propose that you don't actually even need `GROUP BY` here.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  sticky first an then post then you need  order by orum_topics.sticky, forum_posts.posted eg:

```
  SELECT 
      forum_posts.posted_by, 
      forum_posts.posted, 
      forum_topics.id, 
      forum_topics.subject, 
      forum_topics.sticky, 
      forum_topics.closed 
  FROM 
      forum_posts 
  LEFT JOIN 
      forum_topics 
  ON 
      forum_topics.id=forum_posts.topic_id 
  WHERE forum_topics.forum_id=$forumdata->id 
  GROUP BY forum_topics.id 
  ORDER BY forum_topics.sticky DESC, forum_posts.posted DESC
```